# The field does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL

Tags: python, database, django

I have no idea what Django is trying to tell me. I have a model, `WeekTwo`, which inherits from `Week`, which inherits from `modelsModel`. I have another model, `UserProfile`. I want to use `WeekTwo` as a OneToOne Key in `UserProfile`, so I inserted the following line of code:

```
weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo)
```

However, when I try to migrate my database using `python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto`, I get the following error:

```
The field 'UserProfile.weekTwo' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
```

I tried adding `default=0` to my `weekTwo` declaration, but now I'm getting this error when I try the schema migration:

```
IntegrityError: column weekTwo_id is not unique
```

Moreover, south is now telling me that I am in an `interim state between migrations` and that I `might be able to recover`. I literally have no idea what any of this means.

Comment: Have you read the docs? :) http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part2.html

Comment: It was originally telling you that because your new field was mandatory, all your existing rows in the table would need to be updated. If you had migrated, it would have asked you to enter a default value. If you haven't migrated, you should be able to delete the two migration and start again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Be aware before going further, be sure that if South already did any migration that has been failed, It's better to redo|recover to the last `migration` that was working.*

You have two options here, at first you can do [`Data Migration`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations). Look at [ref](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#datamigration) also.

In Second way You can make `weekTwo` field `null` and `blank` first

```
weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then let South generate a migration for you by

```
python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto
```

I'm sure South won't complain about it now, Then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If everything is okay now, You can now get back and change to `weekTwo` field to

```
weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo)
```

And `generate` migration then `migrate` them.

Anyway, When south find out your field in not `NULL` and doesn't have a `default` value, at the `schemamigration` step it will suggest you to provide a value for it, Again here your field is `OneToOneField`, because even south gives you chance to provide a default value for your existed record on model again uniqueness of weekTwo field will raise an error.

I think still you have to go with **Data Migration** if second way didn't work, Or gives it a shot and try the second way this time instead of make it `null`, `blank` change the whole `Field` type. Try it with;

```
weekTwo = models.ForeignKey(WeekTwo)
```

But keep in mind **Data migration** would be definitely smarter and standard way here.

Comment: Hm, went through those steps but am still getting the same error once I take out the null=True and blank=True.